# Join in Pandas dataframe (Auto conversion from date to date-time?)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to use the join function to combine the close price of all 500 stocks in 5 year period (2013-02-08 to 2018-02-07), where each column represent a stock, with the index of the dataframe being the dates.

But the join function in pandas seems to automatically change the date format (index), rendering all the entries in the combined dataframe to be NaN.

The code to import and preview the file:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv('all_stocks_5yr.csv')

df.head()
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Wq4.png)

```
# df.info()
df['Name'].unique().shape   #There are 505 stock names in total

# dates = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max()) #check the date range
```

Single out the close prices:

```
close_prices = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)  #Make the index column to be the dates

# close_prices.head()
```

`symbols = df['Name'].unique(). #Denote the stock names as an array`

So I tried to test the result for each stock using the first 3 stocks:

```
i = 1
for symbol in symbols:
    df_sym = df[df['Name']==symbol] 
    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(data=df_sym['close'].to_numpy() , index = df_sym['date'], columns=[symbol])

    print(df_tmp)                #print the temporary dataframes
 

    i += 1
    if i >3: break
```

And the results were expected, a dataframe indexed by date and only one stock:

```
              AAL
date             
2013-02-08  14.75
2013-02-11  14.46
2013-02-12  14.27
2013-02-13  14.66
2013-02-14  13.99
...           ...
2018-02-01  53.88
2018-02-02  52.10
2018-02-05  49.76
2018-02-06  51.18
2018-02-07  51.40

[1259 rows x 1 columns]
                AAPL
date                
2013-02-08   67.8542
2013-02-11   68.5614
2013-02-12   66.8428
2013-02-13   66.7156
2013-02-14   66.6556
...              ...
2018-02-01  167.7800
2018-02-02  160.5000
2018-02-05  156.4900
2018-02-06  163.0300
2018-02-07  159.5400

[1259 rows x 1 columns]
...
```

Now here's part I find very confusing: I checked what happens **when combining first 3 stock dataframes using join function**, with index 'date':

```
i = 1
for symbol in symbols:
    df_sym = df[df['Name']==symbol] 
    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(data=df_sym['close'].to_numpy() , index = df_sym['date'], columns=[symbol])
  
    close_prices = close_prices.join(df_tmp)
    i += 1
    if i >3: break

close_prices.head()
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqVDo.png)

Somehow **the index changed from date to date-time format**, and therefore naturally "join" function will recognize that none of the entries matches with the new index, and automatically put a NA there for every single entry.

What caused the date to have changed to date-time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('all_stocks_5yr.csv')
out = df1.pivot(index='date', columns='Name', values='close')
```

Output:

```
>>> df.iloc[:, :8]
Name            A    AAL     AAP      AAPL    ABBV    ABC    ABT     ACN
date                                                                    
2013-02-08  45.08  14.75   78.90   67.8542   36.25  46.89  34.41   73.31
2013-02-11  44.60  14.46   78.39   68.5614   35.85  46.76  34.26   73.07
2013-02-12  44.62  14.27   78.60   66.8428   35.42  46.96  34.30   73.37
2013-02-13  44.75  14.66   78.97   66.7156   35.27  46.64  34.46   73.56
2013-02-14  44.58  13.99   78.84   66.6556   36.57  46.77  34.70   73.13
...           ...    ...     ...       ...     ...    ...    ...     ...
2018-02-01  72.83  53.88  117.29  167.7800  116.34  99.29  62.18  160.46
2018-02-02  71.25  52.10  113.93  160.5000  115.17  96.02  61.69  156.90
2018-02-05  68.22  49.76  109.86  156.4900  109.51  91.90  58.73  151.83
2018-02-06  68.45  51.18  112.20  163.0300  111.20  91.54  58.86  154.69
2018-02-07  68.06  51.40  109.93  159.5400  113.62  94.22  58.67  155.15

[1259 rows x 8 columns]
```

Source 'all_stocks_5yr.csv': [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rohitjain454/all-stocks-5yr?select=all_stocks_5yr.csv)